# Are you supposed to modify the Elastic theme files directly, or copy the entire directory to extend it?

Tags: roundcube

It seems like this would end up being overwritten every time you unpack an update no?

Answer (score 1):

You can extend skins. You basically create a new skin and include `"extends": "larry"` in the meta.json file.
Now everything you dont provide will be fetched from there.
see [RoundCube Wiki](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/wiki/Skins)

Comment: That isn't the question. If you extend the Elastic theme, you are unable to update it as it would override any changes you make. The main sass file is empty in the repository, so if they happen to add something to it or change it in any way, then my version would be overridden.

Comment: You create your own skin in its own folder. But instead of writing (or copying) everything from the original skin, you set a link to it. Whenever the orignal skin is updated, nothing in your skin changes, but everything you linked to WILL of course change.